# How to define types when receiving array objects in vue props

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

Thank you for reading.

When receiving array objects in vue props, which of the following codes is the correct type definition?

```
// Value of props

const propsValue = [
  {foo:'aaa'},
  {bar:'bbb'},
  {baz:'ccc'}
]
```

```
// Option 1

const props = defineProps({
  propsValue: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
})
```

```
// Option ２

const props = defineProps({
  propsValue: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {},
  },
})
```

Some people say that it is more correct to write "Array" since we receive an array.

However, others say it is more correct to write "object", which is the content of the array.

Comment: The correct type would be an array a list of objects is also an array. The misleading part is, that  when you use `typeof []` it would give you `object`. The reason behind that is, that Arrays in JavaScript are Array Type objects. Nevertheless, in Vue you have to use `type: Array` in your case Option 1

Comment: i know this is unrelated to your question, but if you want to define complex types as props, you may consider using typescript and the interface `PropType<Array<{foo:string,bar:string,baz:string}>>` to achieve this

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
I will use `type: Array` and will also consider `PropType`.